# Songs are increasing in time when I add them to my Ipod?

Tags: itunes, music, ipod-touch

I'm adding some songs from my iTunes onto my iPod and 1 of the 2 songs is 4:31 min long. When I add it to my iPod and then play it ONLY on my iPod, the time changes to 10:19 min long. And, it doesn't stop at 4:31 and start again. I don't even know what is wrong with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that particular song was encoded with a *variable* bit rate instead of a *constant* one.  While this improves compression efficiency, unless the MP3 has proper VBR headers, the length will be computed incorrectly on some programs/devices.

You can use the tool [VBRFix](http://home.gna.org/vbrfix/) to add this header to existing VBR-encoded MP3s (`vbrfix` is also available from most Linux package repositories).